# Depencencies in Cargo.toml file Solana-SDK and Solana-Client doesn't work

Tags: solana-program, cargo, solana-sdk, solana-client, rustc

Hello I am trying desperately to use solana-sdk and solana-client but when I do cargo build-bpf it doesn't work. Can someone help me please?

When I use only solana-client as a dependency the compilation goes well

[image]

But when i specify solana-client i get many errors:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Now Only with solana-sdk :
[image]

Here is a capture that shows the versions I have of solana, cargo , rustup, rustc
[image]

Someone can help me please ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Solana documentation](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions):

- On-chain Rust programs support most of Rust's libstd, libcore, and liballoc, as well as many 3rd party crates.
- There are some limitations since these programs run in a resource-constrained, single-threaded environment, and must be deterministic:
- No access to:
- `rand`
- `std::fs`
- `std::net`
- `std::future`
- `std::process`
- `std::sync`
- `std::task`
- `std::thread`
- `std::time`
- Limited access to:
- `std::hash`
- `std::os`

Since `solana-client` crate depends on some of the restricted code like `std::net`, you can't use it inside programs.

**All on-chain programs must be deterministic.**